# difference between Rest web service method call and non Rest web service method call or normal method call

Tags: ajax, rest, service, web, call

Can anyone please let me know the difference between rest web service method call and normal method call.

I developed a website, in which I invoked a method in controller using the following way,

```
 @RequestMapping("/something.do")
```

and now I changed the same method to web service. Now I invoke the same method like

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/something.do",headers="Accept=application/json")
```

And the URL i used in the AJAX call before and after converting to web service is "something.do". Everything is working fine.

My question is, if it is Rest web service then my URL should be something like 
`locahost/ProjectDisplayName/something.do`. But it is working fine even when I make ajax call with `something.do` in URL. If this is correct what is difference between them?

Or please correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See when you make rest call, and intercept it using controller. 
Then you can send different parameters along with the call.

You can format your url before call `restTemplate.executeService(Object ... obj)` 
so that it will map to below method.

```
eg.
<code>
 @RequestMapping(value = "/something/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody
    testJsonMessage getDataById(
            @PathVariable("id") String id) {
}
</code>
```